# yarn build + create-react-app + env variables in public JS file

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm using yarn and env-cmd to build my React app and manage our environment variables. Here is my package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build:local": "env-cmd .env.local react-scripts build",
    "build:uat": "env-cmd .env.uat react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

It works fine for the JS files under the `/src/` folder and in `/public/index.htm` too.

**Question:**
How can I use a variable in a `public/*.js` file ?

My variable is named *REACT_APP_URL*. I've tried to use `%REACT_APP_URL%` or `process.env.REACT_APP_URL` without success.

**EDIT**: I want to inject these variables at build time.

Answer (score 2):

I have a file .env.development in the same src with package.json
this works for me

"start": "REACT_APP_ENV=develpoment npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",

Comment: Are you able to use your variables in `public/*.js` ?

Comment: @ToineSeiter Does it worked? I am facing same issue. And I am not getting how to solve it.